# How can I clone an EC2 server?

Tags: amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 server that I've configured. Is there a good way to duplicate it?

I'd like to duplicate everything I've installed on it, so I have a second one.

Comment: Why would you downvote this question? You should seriously explain why. Yes, I know I could write a script or use Docker or whatever to make a template, but I'm talking about a server with some arbitrary stuff done to it that I'd like to clone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To clone an instance

1. ***Right click*** on that instance
2. From the dropdown hover over ***Image***
3. Select ***Create Image***

You can see your image being created by clicking

***AMI*** on the ***Images*** section on the left Pane

Once the status of your image turns to *available*, you can launch instances out of that image (again by right clicking on the respective image)